# How do you determine which subview is currently being displayed in a scrollview?

Tags: swift

I am a swift beginner. I have the following view setup as in the screenshot below.

It is made up of a CollectionView at the top with two cells (completed and open) and a UISCrollsview with two TableView subviews right below it.

I wish to be able to scroll to the next view (Open Tableview list) and indicate that by changing the selected cell at the top (OPEN). Vice-versa if  I tap on OPEN, I want the ScrollView below to automatically scroll to the correct subview.

So my question is:

1. How do I determine what the current subview that is being scrolled to being displayed?
2. How do I scroll to the correct subview based on the selected cell from the collectionview at top?

[image]

Here is my code to the controller class:

```
class OrdersViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var ordersListSV: UIScrollView!

var orderStatus: [String] = ["Completed", "Open"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "ORDERS"

    //creating the first view to show
    let completedOrderView: CompletedOrdersTableViewController = CompletedOrdersTableViewController(nibName: "CompletedOrdersTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    //showing the first view
    self.addChildViewController(completedOrderView)
    self.ordersListSV.addSubview(completedOrderView.view)
    completedOrderView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    //creating the second view to show
    let openOrderView: OpenOrdersTableViewController = OpenOrdersTableViewController(nibName: "OpenOrdersTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    //showing the second view
    self.addChildViewController(openOrderView)
    self.ordersListSV.addSubview(openOrderView.view)
    openOrderView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    //Adding the second view to the frame
    var OpenOrderViewFrame: CGRect = openOrderView.view.frame
    OpenOrderViewFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    openOrderView.view.frame = OpenOrderViewFrame

    //Allowing it to scroll over to the second view
    self.ordersListSV.contentSize = CGSize(width: ordersListSV.bounds.width * 2, height: ordersListSV.bounds.height)

}
```

}

extension OrdersViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return orderStatus.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OrderStatusCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderStatusCollectionViewCell

    cell.lbOrderState.text = orderStatus[indexPath.row].uppercased()

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.item)


}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidDisappear(false)

    let indexPathForFirstRow = NSIndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)

    collectionView?.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)

}
```

}

Comment: why don't use tag?

Comment: not 100% percent sure what you mean? I'm new to Swift.